# React nested Route that needs to match ../ up one level

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have an application where I need to render different pages for different routes, such as `"/articles/*"`

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/articles/:article/:tab" element={<ArticlePage />} />
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

Then inside of `ArticlePage`, I use both the `:article` and `:tab` parameters for miscellaneous purposes, before finally rendering the `ArticleContent`.

```
function ArticlePage() {
  const { article, tab } = useParams()

  return (
    <Container SomeAttributeThatDependsOnTab={tab}>
      <h1>{article}</h1>
      <h2>selected tab: {tab}</h2> 
      <ArticleContent />
    </Container>
  )
}
```

However, `ArticleContent` itself needs to display different components based on the `:tab` parameter, such as the `"/summary"` tab resulting in a component built for plain Markdown text, the `"/examples"` tab built for specialized code snippets, and so on, requiring a second use of `Routes`.

I attempt to do it like this:

```
function ArticleContent() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/summary" element={<MarkdownContent />} />
      {/* i.e `articles/singleton/summary/ */}
      <Route path="/examples" element={<ExamplesContent />} />
      {/* i.e `articles/singleton/examples/ */}
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

but this results in a bug where `<Route path="/summary"` attempts to match `"articles/:article/summary/summary"`, because nested routes use relative routing, when I need it to instead match `"articles/:article/summary"`.

I attempt to solve this by removing the `:tab` in the parent route

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/articles/:article/" element={<ArticlePage />} />
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

but this breaks the `const { article, tab } = useParams()` in `ArticlePage` now, as `tab` is not detected.

Is it possible for me to use `"../"` in the nested route?

Example:

```
function ArticleContent() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="../summary" element={<MarkdownContent />} />
      <Route path="../examples" element={<ExamplesContent />} />
    </Routes>
  )
}

function ArticlePage() {
  const { article, tab } = useParams()

  return (
    <Container SomeAttributeThatDependsOnTab={tab}>
      <h1>{article}</h1>
      <h2>selected tab: {tab}</h2> 
      <ArticleContent />
    </Container>
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/articles/:article/:tab" element={<ArticlePage />} />
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `"."` and `".."` as the leading part of the path string as far as I know, and I certainly tried that first in case I was mistaken, but you can use a different pattern to conditionally return/render content in the `ArticleContent` component.

Abstractly the `Routes` component functions as a `switch` statement that conditionally returns specific JSX based on matching a path value. The `Routes` component replaced the older React-Router `Switch` component.

Update `ArticleContent` to read the current `tab` route path param and use a `switch` statement to return the appropriate JSX.

Example:

```
function ArticleContent() {
  const { tab } = useParams();

  switch(tab) {
    case "summary":
      return <MarkdownContent />;

    case "examples":
      return <ExamplesContent />;

    default:
      return null;
  }
}
```

[image: Edit react-nested-route-that-needs-to-match-up-one-level]

Comment: I considered this approach, but assumed directly doing a plain `switch` statement for conditional rendering was naive or would result in problems in the React lifecycle or whatever. Otherwise, why do people even use react-router, if they can achieve the exact same behavior by just directly using if/switch statements? Does `<Routes>` just encapsulate a few extra steps necessary for you to avoid having to constantly rewrite?

Comment: @pinkboid People use React-Router because it is a *routing* ***and*** *navigation* library. It abstracts away the logic of conditionally rendering UI based on a path and provides a way to navigate between "pages" using a browser's Navigation API. At the end of the day you are using Javascript, and `switch` statements are valid Javascript. I don't suspect you'd have any rendering/lifecycle issues using it.